# FATAL EXCEPTION : you must specify a way to create the tab content

Tags: android, tabs, android-tabhost, tabcontainer

Im try to make customized menu tab for my app, then im found the similiar source with my needed stuf, im combined the code from here [source1](http://pmsdobak.tistory.com/entry/Custom-Tab-%EA%B5%AC%ED%98%84) and here [source2](http://joshclemm.com/blog/?p=136)
but when try to running im got FATAL EXCEPTION like this :

```
06-03 16:30:05.305: E/AndroidRuntime(633): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-03 16:30:05.305: E/AndroidRuntime(633): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.hynra.seribucandi/com.hynra.seribucandi.CandiAbang}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: you must specify a way to create the tab content
06-03 16:30:05.305: E/AndroidRuntime(633):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
06-03 16:30:05.305: E/AndroidRuntime(633):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
06-03 16:30:05.305: E/AndroidRuntime(633):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
06-03 16:30:05.305: E/AndroidRuntime(633):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
06-03 16:30:05.305: E/AndroidRuntime(633):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-03 16:30:05.305: E/AndroidRuntime(633):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-03 16:30:05.305: E/AndroidRuntime(633):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
06-03 16:30:05.305: E/AndroidRuntime(633):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-03 16:30:05.305: E/AndroidRuntime(633):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-03 16:30:05.305: E/AndroidRuntime(633):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
06-03 16:30:05.305: E/AndroidRuntime(633):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
06-03 16:30:05.305: E/AndroidRuntime(633):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-03 16:30:05.305: E/AndroidRuntime(633): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: you must specify a way to create the tab content
06-03 16:30:05.305: E/AndroidRuntime(633):  at android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:202)
06-03 16:30:05.305: E/AndroidRuntime(633):  at com.hynra.seribucandi.CandiAbang.setupTab(CandiAbang.java:55)
06-03 16:30:05.305: E/AndroidRuntime(633):  at com.hynra.seribucandi.CandiAbang.onCreate(CandiAbang.java:36)
06-03 16:30:05.305: E/AndroidRuntime(633):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
06-03 16:30:05.305: E/AndroidRuntime(633):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
06-03 16:30:05.305: E/AndroidRuntime(633):  ... 11 more
```

Here the java file

```
package com.hynra.seribucandi;

import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabContentFactory;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.ImageView;


public class CandiAbang extends TabActivity {
    final static String INFO = "Info";
    final static String MAP = "Map";
    final static String GALL = "Gallery";

    private TabHost tabHost;
    private void setupTabHost() {
        tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        tabHost.setup();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.c_abang);

        setupTabHost();
        tabHost.getTabWidget().setDividerDrawable(R.drawable.tab_divider);

        setupTab(new TextView(this), "INFO");
        setupTab(new TextView(this), "MAP");
        setupTab(new TextView(this), "GALL");
        tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);

    }


    private void setupTab(final View view, final String tag) {
        View tabview = createTabView(tabHost.getContext(), tag);
        TabSpec setContent = tabHost.newTabSpec(tag).setIndicator(tabview);

        if(tag.equals(INFO))
            setContent.setContent(new Intent(this, AbangInfo.class));
        else if(tag.equals(MAP))
            setContent.setContent(new Intent(this, AbangMap.class));
        else if(tag.equals(GALL))
            setContent.setContent(new Intent(this, AbangGall.class));

        tabHost.addTab(setContent);

        }

    private static View createTabView(final Context context, final String text) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.tab2_bg, null);
    TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tabsText);
    tv.setText(text);
    return view;
    }



}
```

And this for the Layout file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TabHost
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            >
            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />
              <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    /> 
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>
</LinearLayout>
```

For the background selector im using this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/tab2_selector"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/tabsImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tabsText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textSize="12dip"
        android:textColor="@drawable/tab2_text"
        /> </LinearLayout>
```

When im running, i just got exception warning : **you must specify a way to create the tab content** how can i solved this problem ? help me. Thanks before

Comment: I had this problem, too, but after adding setIndicator as indicated in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14674881/cant-find-the-cause-you-must-specify-a-way-to-create-the-tab-indicator , I was able to get it to run w/o the error.

Comment: This might help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19324352/android-fragmenttabhost-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-you-must-specify