# Android: FragmentTabHost - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: you must specify a way to create the tab content

Tags: android, fragment-tab-host

I have the following in a class for creating a `FragmentTabHost`:

```
public class TabsActivity extends FragmentActivity {
private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tabs);
    mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);

    TabHost.TabSpec exploreSpec = mTabHost.newTabSpec("explore").setIndicator("Explore", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.exploreicon));
    mTabHost.addTab(exploreSpec);
}

}
```

I have a separate .xml file for setting up the host as shown in the android support site. This is all in a second activity. My primary activity has a group of images. Clicking one loads this activity. The app runs initially. As soon as I tap an image to load this activity though it crashes. Inside LogCat I found the following error:

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: you must specify a way to create the tab content`

I can't seem to find any thing on this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without being able to see your xml file (R.layout.tabs) I'd say something is not set up quite right.

**Instead of:**

```
TabHost.TabSpec exploreSpec = mTabHost.newTabSpec("explore").setIndicator("Explore", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.exploreicon));
    mTabHost.addTab(exploreSpec);
```

**Try:**

```
mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("explore").setIndicator("Explore", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.exploreicon)), TheAssociatedFragmentTab.class, null);
```

**R.layout.tabs.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#ffffff" >

    <android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ffffff" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
</LinearLayout>
```

Beyond that you will just need an ExplorerFragment class (extends fragment) which Overrides onCreateView  and inflates the layout for your explorer tab like so..

**ExplorerFragment.java**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,  Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
     super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
     return inflater.inflate(R.layout.explorer_fragment, container, false);
}
```

I didn't try to incorporate an image on my tabs, but this code works for me. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Yep. I didn't realize I actually needed a content file as well for the tab. I figured it would just load and empty view. I've since done that. This is correct.