# Tabs on Android

Tags: android

I am trying to implement a simple code only to show two tabs on Android and later add content dividing into two Activities, one to show examples with IF and the other with SWITCH.

I created the XML and Java without problems, I believe.

After run, does not enter the application, presenting a message that needed to be closed. I have been using Android Studio, is there any compatibility issue?

My Java Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

TabHost tabHost=(TabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
tabHost.setup();

TabSpec spec1=tabHost.newTabSpec("IF");
spec1.setContent(R.id.IF);

TabSpec spec2=tabHost.newTabSpec("SWITCH");
spec2.setContent(R.id.SWITCH);

tabHost.addTab(spec1);
tabHost.addTab(spec2);
}
}
```

My XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/tabHost"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>
<TabWidget
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@android:id/tabs"
/>
<FrameLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
>

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/IF"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingTop="60px"
>
<TextView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="100px"
android:text="Esta e a aba 01"
android:id="@+id/txt1"
/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/SWITCH"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingTop="60px"
>
<TextView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="100px"
android:text="Esta e a aba 2"
android:id="@+id/txt2"
/>

</LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Errors:

```
12-27 01:24:29.300  30658-30658/com.example.luizhmu.aulas_android_if_switch E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.luizhmu.aulas_android_if_switch, PID: 30658
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.luizhmu.aulas_android_if_switch/com.example.luizhmu.aulas_android_if_switch.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: you must specify a way to create the tab indicator.
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: you must specify a way to create the tab indicator.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [Can't find the cause "you must specify a way to create the tab indicator"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14674881/cant-find-the-cause-you-must-specify-a-way-to-create-the-tab-indicator), you need specify a label as the tab indicator, try:

```
TabHost.TabSpec spec1=tabHost.newTabSpec("IF");
spec1.setContent(R.id.IF);
spec1.setIndicator("your label");

TabHost.TabSpec spec2=tabHost.newTabSpec("SWITCH");
spec2.setContent(R.id.SWITCH);
spec2.setIndicator("your label 2");

tabHost.addTab(spec1);
tabHost.addTab(spec2);
```