# ListView in TabHost

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm trying to put a listView (existing list named sitesList) in a TabHost but when I run my app, it closes (without the code for tabhost the app works), here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends TabActivity {

    private SitesAdapter mAdapter;
    private ListView sitesList;
    private static final String Noutati = "Noutati";
    private static final String Favorite = "Favorite";
    private static final String PROFILE_SPEC = "Profile";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.i("StackSites", "OnCreate()");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();


        TabSpec inboxSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec(Noutati);
        Intent inboxIntent = new Intent(this, Noutati.class);
        inboxSpec.setContent(inboxIntent);


        TabSpec outboxSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec(Favorite);
        //Intent outboxIntent = new Intent(this, OutboxActivity.class);
        //outboxSpec.setContent(outboxIntent);

        tabHost.addTab(inboxSpec); 
        tabHost.addTab(outboxSpec); 


        sitesList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.sitesList);

        ... 


public class Noutati extends ListActivity {

    private ListView sitesList;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.noutati);
        sitesList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.sitesList);
        this.setListAdapter((android.widget.ListAdapter) sitesList);

    }
}
```

Activity_main

```
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

noutati.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/sitesList"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Thank you very much

Comment: Post the error message.

Comment: i have no error message, just application doesn't run, it closes

Comment: the code worked before I started adding the code for tabhost and trying to put the listView in one of the tabhost's tab..

Comment: What do you see in LogCat?

Comment: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.andrian.jurnaltv/com.example.andrian.jurnaltv.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: you must specify a way to create the tab indicator.

Comment: at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2400)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2458)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172)

Comment: at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1305)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5598)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: you must specify a way to create the tab indicator.
            at android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:223)
            at com.example.andrian.jurnaltv.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:53)

Comment: or can anybody give me a link to working code: tabhost with a listview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:
I see that you have named your variable Noutati and your class Noutati. Thy changing the variable to something like noutatiName.

As I have never encountered this before, I'm not sure this will work, but the error most likely appears because you have to set the indicator for each tab spec.

So after `TabSpec inboxSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec(Noutati);` you should also type `inboxSpec .setIndicator("Notuati");`

Hope it helps!

Also you should do that after `TabSpec outboxSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec(Favorite);`

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14674881/cant-find-the-cause-you-must-specify-a-way-to-create-the-tab-indicato)

Comment: it did not solve the problem. do you have a link to a working example tabhost with listview?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14674881/cant-find-the-cause-you-must-specify-a-way-to-create-the-tab-indicator

Comment: thanks! is it ok my noutati.java file?

Comment: So @Andrew did this solve your problem?, Can you update the code please?

Comment: Roberto yes! thank you very much!